# Collection #1: Do we know the source of the leaks?

Tags: password-management, data-leakage

With Collection #1 yet another large data set of email addresses and passwords was found *out there*. I happens that one of my frequently used email addresses shows up as 'pwned' [when checked against the list](https://haveibeenpwned.com). However (!), this has been the case for a long time - since some leaks that lie back many years.

- Do we know the source of the Collection #1 data, and especially if there is significant **new data** from new leaks?

Or this is famed Collection #1 simply an aggregation of older existing lists, many of which are old and already well known? (And well discussed in the media...)

I am already using dedicated, long, generated, random passwords on all my accounts (managed in a password safe). Now if I knew that certain online services were the source of leaks (i.e. got hacked or similar) I might spend some special attention on making sure that these accounts get locked / new passwords / etc...

But I'd rather not go and change all my countless passwords all over literally hundreds of accounts.

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2019/01/21/hackers-who-leaked-collection-1-are-selling-10-times-more-data-but-you-dont-need-to-panic/  multiple different sources

Comment: And if you're using LastPass, it allows auto-changing compromised passwords (i.e. if your password has been found in data breaches).  This works for popular sites, afaik. You need to visit the "Security Challenge Center" and calculate your score. To make it work smoothly, I usually log out of these sites, and select bulk change.

Comment: Thanks @schroeder, if you expand that into an answer I'd happily accept it.

Comment: Sure, except that is has been known from the start. https://www.troyhunt.com/the-773-million-record-collection-1-data-reach/ "Collection #1 is a set of email addresses and passwords totalling 2,692,818,238 rows. It's made up of many different individual data breaches from literally thousands of different sources."